# To pull count of a specific column of 10k tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT Count(COLUMN_NAME)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TableName' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DatabaseName'
```

I tried this to pull count from a single table.
How to achieve this with multiple tables which is more than 10k

Comment: " How to achieve this will multiple tables which is more than 10k " Simply Remove `TABLE_NAME = 'TableName' AND ` from the query?.. Hard to said without expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove your filter condition of Table name AS below

```
SELECT Count(COLUMN_NAME)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DatabaseName'
```